# Getting an error when requesting data from http

Tags: flutter, http, dart, web, network-programming

I don't know what I need to do, I tried to change my URL. But I am still getting this error.

**Here is the error.**

```
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
)
```

**Below is the code where I request the data**

```
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> venuesData;

  Future<void> fetchAndSetVenues() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(venuesURL));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      venuesData = extractedData;
      print(venuesData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  // events
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> eventsData;

  Future<void> fetchAndSetEvents() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(eventsURL));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      eventsData = extractedData;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

**And here are my URLs**

```
String eventsURL = 'http://medeni.art/api/v1/events?page=1'

String venuesURL = 'http://medeni.art/api/v1/venues'
```

Comment: Hi There. you haven't added enough code for people to be able to help. The code you have provided has no issues. add full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs in `json.decode` method. For any reason, if http request get error, the `json.decode` should not be called. You can check request response status code.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/whatsit/create');
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
if(response.statusCode ==200){
  final result = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Comment: Hey @RezaM thank you! It is solved the problem.